# While let does not stop even when the while's condition is fulfilled

Tags: rust, while-loop, let

I'm new to rust, and I'm trying to code a program that opens a websocket for 10 seconds, receive the data from it and then stops. The piece of code is the following.

```
let now = Instant::now();
while let n=now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10  {
    let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message");
    let msg = match msg {
        tungstenite::Message::Text(s) => { s }
        _ => { panic!() }
    };
    let parsed: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&msg).expect("Can't parse to JSON");
    let price_str=parsed["p"].as_str().unwrap();
    let price: f32 = price_str.parse().unwrap();
    

    write!(f,"1 \t").expect("unable to write");
    write!(f, "\t\t {} \n", price).expect("unable to write");
    println!("{}",n);
    
}
```

n becomes false after 10 seconds, but the loop never ends. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while let n` binds the result of the expression `now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10` to `n`. This binding can never fail, thus your loop never exits.

The compiler emits a lint to prevent such mistakes:

```
warning: irrefutable `while let` pattern
  --> src/lib.rs:24:11
   |
24 |     while let n = now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10 {
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(irrefutable_let_patterns)]` on by default
   = note: this pattern will always match, so the loop will never exit
   = help: consider instead using a `loop { ... }` with a `let` inside it
```

To fix your snippet, you'll need to remove the `let n` part. Or in a more unusual and rather unidiomatic manner, you can pattern match on the value returned by `now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10` through:

```
while let true = now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10 {
    // do your thing
}
```

If you want access to the loop control variable, you can still bind it to a variable through:

```
let now = std::time::Instant::now();
while let n @ true = now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10 {
    println!("loop_control={}", n)
}
```

As @Jmb mentions in a comment, there is another issue that's not a compiler error: The loop body may block indefinitely, thus rendering the timeout ineffective.

Comment: Another issue with the OP code is that it will only exit the loop if `now.elapsed().as_secs() < 10` _immediately after processing a message._ So if no message is received, the code will wait indefinitely.